# SymPy: Delete multiple rows of a matrix

Tags: row, sympy

Is there a method to delete multiple rows of a matrix in SymPy (without using NumPy)?

I understand that `.row_del()` can only delete one row at a time.

```
from sympy import *

a_1_1, a_1_2, a_1_3 = symbols ('a_1_1 a_1_2 a_1_3')
a_2_1, a_2_2, a_2_3 = symbols ('a_2_1 a_2_2 a_2_3')
a_3_1, a_3_2, a_3_3 = symbols ('a_3_1 a_3_2 a_3_3')

A = Matrix ([
    [a_1_1, a_1_2, a_1_3], 
    [a_2_1, a_2_2, a_2_3], 
    [a_3_1, a_3_2, a_3_3]
])

A.row_del (1 : 2)
```

does not (yet?) work:

```
    A.row_del (1 : 2)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `np.delete` is a complicated function that returns a new array.  The exact action depends what you want to keep, converse of the drop.  For a slice it probably concatenates the two remaining blocks.  So I'm not surprised that `sympy` only offers the  one row at a time option.  `sympy` Matrices are small compared so `numpy's`, so avoiding 'loops'  isn't so important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slicing or outer indexing to select the rows that you want:

```
In [8]: A = MatrixSymbol('A', 3, 3).as_explicit()

In [9]: A
Out[9]: 
⎡A₀₀  A₀₁  A₀₂⎤
⎢             ⎥
⎢A₁₀  A₁₁  A₁₂⎥
⎢             ⎥
⎣A₂₀  A₂₁  A₂₂⎦

In [10]: A[:1,:]
Out[10]: [A₀₀  A₀₁  A₀₂]

In [11]: A[[0,2],:]
Out[11]: 
⎡A₀₀  A₀₁  A₀₂⎤
⎢             ⎥
⎣A₂₀  A₂₁  A₂₂⎦
```

Comment: Yap, that works. Since you used `MatrixSymbol`, and I know I will be nailed to the cross for that question: Is there a way to autocreate matrices with a_1_1 as their first element? Background: I teach mathematics and my students are used to see a_1_1 as the first matrix element:

[Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) 

Well, I can always delete the first row and the first column. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The `:` syntax to select a slice of items is only supported inside of square brackets in Python. That's why the error is SyntaxError. So even if the `row_del` function did support deleting multiple rows at once, the syntax for it would not look like `row_del(1:2)`, because that's not valid Python.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your follow-up question, part of the beauty of working in Python is that you can write your own utility functions to make things work the way you want. So you could make a function to create a matrix that automatically comes back with indices as desired. Note, too, that selecting rows or columns with a list will put them in the requested order:

```
>>> a1rc = lambda a,r,c: MatrixSymbol(a, r+1, c+1).as_explicit()[1:,1:]
>>> a1rc("A",3,4)
Matrix([
[A[1, 1], A[1, 2], A[1, 3], A[1, 4]],
[A[2, 1], A[2, 2], A[2, 3], A[2, 4]],
[A[3, 1], A[3, 2], A[3, 3], A[3, 4]]])
>>> _[[2,0],:]  # row 2 will come first, then row 0
Matrix([
[A[3, 1], A[3, 2], A[3, 3], A[3, 4]],
[A[1, 1], A[1, 2], A[1, 3], A[1, 4]]])
```